# The logo not taking full height of the header

Tags: html, css

I need to set the height of the logo same as the header. Though I set the height of the logo as 100% it doesn't take the height of the header. I am not sure how to set the height of the logo as the header height. Here is my code

**app.css**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border-top:none;
}

.navbar {


    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 10px 15px;

}

.navbar img {

    width : 100%; 
    height : 100%;
}
```

**Master page**

You can see the reference of the logo in the header element

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a  href="#"><img src="~/Images/NGSR-logo.jpg" /> </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Requests</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Country <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Save View</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

</header>
```

**Header view**

[image]

Comment: question: what happens if you remove padding from .navbar (css)

Comment: Could you possible create a fiddle of this or something with the full CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set a max-width for the logo image:

```
.navbar-header img{
  max-width:280px;
}
```

and then set padding to zero for the navbar:

```
.navbar{
  padding:0;
}
```

For my example I picked a random logo from google, however that should give you the general idea!

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/captain_theo/f1a5bda1/

Comment: This seems to work. But how did you determine the max-width as 280px ?

Comment: @Tom That I just used because the logo that I found was too big (almost 800px). So I just thought to set a max-width... It's really not necessary to use if you have an image that fits exactly as you want it to. By the way, if my answer solved your issue would you also accept it? Thank you!